Which Coxeter Groups Are Hyperbolic Groups?
This question came up in my abstract algebra class today, and cursory research did not find a satisfactory answer.
Which Coxeter groups are hyperbolic groups (in the sense of Gromov)? I know that some classes of them are, but are there any counterexamples?

@WillJagy: Humphreys uses different definition of hyperbolicity: OP had Gromov-hyperbolicity in mind. Gromov-hyperbolic Coxeter groups exist in all dimensions.

A finitely generated Coxeter group is hyperbolic if and only if it does not contain $\mathbb Z^2$ (this is Moussong's theorem).

@MoisheKohan  thanks. I guess  I'll leave the screen capture for now; perhaps the OP will be more specific

G. Moussong in his PhD thesis proved the following characterization of Gromov-hyperbolic Coxeter groups:
Theorem. Suppose that $W$ is a finitely generated Coxeter group with labelled Coxeter graph $G$. Then the following are equivalent:

$W$ is Gromov-hyperbolic.

$W$ does not contains $\mathbb Z^2$.

The graph $G$ does not contain  subgraphs corresponding to:


(i) Euclidean Coxeter groups of dimension $\ge 2$.
(ii) Products of infinite Coxeter groups $W_1\times W_2$.
You can find details in
Davis, Michael W., The geometry and topology of Coxeter groups., London Mathematical Society Monographs Series 32. Princeton, NJ: Princeton University Press (ISBN 978-0-691-13138-2/hbk). xiv, 584 p. (2008). ZBL1142.20020.
Gromov-hyperbolic Coxeter groups exist in all dimensions:
Januszkiewicz, Tadeusz; Świątkowski, Jacek, Hyperbolic Coxeter groups of large dimension., Comment. Math. Helv. 78, No. 3, 555-583 (2003). ZBL1068.20043.
For a simpler construction see
Osajda, Damian, A construction of hyperbolic Coxeter groups., Comment. Math. Helv. 88, No. 2, 353-367 (2013). ZBL1282.20049.
